# Text in anchors horizontal list in Internet Explorer 6 wrapping onto two lines

Tags: css, debugging, internet-explorer, cross-browser, internet-explorer-6

Please view this fiddle in IE6:

http://jsfiddle.net/rS4dE/2/

Unless I add a width of 1% to the li elements of the ul then they balloon to fill all the available space provided by the parent.  If i do add the 1% width hack then some of the text in the hyper links breaks onto two lines which is totally undesirable.

Thanks for looking.

Comment: Not directly to your question, I really like the idea of [this js add-on](http://ie6update.com/) called IE6 Update.  All you do is add the script on your page, and if the user is using IE 6, an HTML element will be created that looks like an MS update bare, and it is a link to Microsoft's newest IE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sorry that you're forced to support IE6.  My idea is to add:

`white-space: nowrap;`

To your `#topmenu li` selector to prevent the text from wrapping.  This shouldn't have any negative effects on any "more modern" browsers either.